# How i can get PhantomDriver process ID

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, process, phantomjs

**Hello to all**

I use selenium phantomJS webDriver and in some cases the drivers still stay in the system after program ends (i use proper exit `driver.Quit()`)

i made app for looking at the process's that's still running with all the information (windowHandle, processID and so on..)

but

How can i get my phantom driver process id to string?

i want to compere after the process and find the program that making the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it if somebody interested:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory);
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
string phantomProcessId = PJSdriverService.ProcessId.ToString();
```